# Outline for Swift Buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I am new into swift programming and i'm trying to make a piano app. Does anyone know hout to put border at buttons in Swift ?
I searched on internet but all tutorials are for an older version of Swift and it's not working anymore.

Comment: Please search. The first hit in [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bswift%5d%20uibutton%20border) should work.

Answer (score 4):

UIButton inherits from UIControl and UIControl inherits from
UIView.
UIView contains CALayer (Core Animation layer) used for rendering.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
button.backgroundColor = .red
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            button.clipsToBounds = true
```

You can easily change the Button attributes values like (borderWidth,borderColor,cornerRadius)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for swift 3

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
// if you want corners to be rounded you can use the corner radus
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
// if you're setting background image to the button and it happens to be not clipped then you can use 
button.clipsToBounds = true
```